# Что быстрей String или UUID?

Tags: java, хеширование

Хотелось бы раз и навсегда выяснить, что лучше и целесообразнее использовать в виде ключа в хэш-коллекциях `String` или `UUID`?

```
Map<String, Value> map = ...
Map<UUID, Value> map = ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Можно посмотреть на реализации функций `hashCode`  в классах `String` и `UUID`.

Для [String](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html):

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a
 * <code>String</code> object is computed as
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
 * </pre></blockquote>
 * using <code>int</code> arithmetic, where <code>s[i]</code> is the
 * <i>i</i>th character of the string, <code>n</code> is the length of
 * the string, and <code>^</code> indicates exponentiation.
 * (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)
 *
 * @return  a hash code value for this object.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Для [UUID](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/UUID.java.html):

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this {@code UUID}.
 *
 * @return  A hash code value for this {@code UUID}
 */
public int hashCode() {
    long hilo = mostSigBits ^ leastSigBits;
    return ((int)(hilo >> 32)) ^ (int) hilo;
}
```

Можно видеть, что для `UUID` вычисления хэша происходит очень быстро, с помощью битовых операций над полями.

Для `String` хэш вычисляется путём прохода по каждому символу строки. Но это происходит для каждого объекта только один раз. После того, как хэш уже был однажды вычислен, он просто хранится в поле класса и возвращается, если он нужен.

При этом нужно отметить разницу в подходах хранения данных в этих классах. В классе `String` строка хранится как массив значений `char`. А в классе `UUID` в двух полях типа `long`. Вследствие этого, объект типа `String`, хранящий UUID, будет занимать куда больше места, чем сам UUID. В строке будет около 36 символов, т.е. 72 байта, плюс расходы на хранение, например, длины строки. В то время как в `UUID` это будет всего 16 байт.

Таким образом, если вы хотите использовать не очень много ключей, но при этом обращение по ним может быть частым, можно использовать `String`. В остальных случаях, особенно, если вам нужно хранить очень много разных ключей, однозначно лучше использовать `UUID`.